# Новый дизайн нас тоже ждёт?

Tags: поддержка, дизайн, нытьё

На SO поменялся дизайн хедера сайта. И он мне не нравится:

- Зачем он сдался фиксированный? Страницу скроллишь, а он место постоянно занимает
- Уменьшена кнопка перехода на главную страницу
- Всё сделано непонятными иконками
- Переставлены все элементы, в том числе:

  - Список сайтов перенесён из первой позиции в последнюю
  - Кнопку справки вообще не нашёл
  - Поиск больше не в углу

Нас это тоже ждёт?

Ну и два скриншота, чтоб были:

[image: SO]

[image: ruSO]

---

Тема с обсуждением на enSO - [Top Navigation Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653)

Comment: *Зачем он сдался фиксированный?* -- выключаемо. Штатными средствами.

Comment: Кнопка справки показывается, но только незарегистрированным пользователям, согласен, это **ужасная идея**.

Comment: Охромили дизайн

Comment: <нытье>а мне больше всего не нравится что все теперь одинаково светлое, мне темная шапка и кнопки вопросы-метки нравились гораздо больше</нытье>

Comment: С другой стороны со всеми редизайнами так, сначала все плюются потому что ломаются интерфейсные привычки, потом привыкают. Не могу с ходу вспомнить ни одного масштабного разового редизайна который с ходу большинству людей бы нравился

Comment: К следующему редизайну точно все привыкнут)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, VS2008 -> VS2010, хотя и не сайт.

Comment: @Qwertiy VS2017 вовсю уже RC ... А Вы тут каких-то мамонтов вспомнили :)

Comment: @alexolut, опубликуете высказанные недостатки на Meta.SE? Вас там уже достаточно хорошо знают (три тысячи репутации, как-никак).

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, `потом привыкают` — они сбили цветовые акценты, сделав светлые элементы на светлом фоне шапки поверх опять же светлой основной части страницы — здравствуй, каша. В придачу, неудобно загонять глаза в верхний правый угол широкоформатного экрана, куда они поместили всю важную для участников информацию. Так что хотя привыкнуть и можно, но постоянный дискомфорт будет  преследовать всё равно.

Comment: @Arhad там и без меня [желающих полно](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update).

Comment: Интересно, как модераторская почта и модераторская очередь выглядят в этом UI.

Comment: А гитхаб так вообще сделал черный хедер пару дней назад. Сволочи!

Comment: @D-side, для входа в справку достаточно добавить `/help` в адресной строке браузера (не тривиальное решение...)

Comment: @avp а предварительно надо зайти на Мету, где найти этот вопрос и ваш комментарий к нему :]

Comment: @D-side, видимо надо понимать, что новый дизайн призван отсекать не достаточно догадливых (а то народу уже слишком много)

Comment: @PashaPash♦: на GitHub [**можно вернуть старый**](https://userstyles.org/styles/138823/white-github). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных кастом стилями. это не то. он будет белым, но в душе навсегда останется черным

Comment: @Qwertiy вот не надо! VS2010 была худшим творением Microsoft. Ну, после Висты и восьмерки...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а мне она прям сразу понравилась. А вот 2012 после неё - нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy да ладно? 2012 по расцветке совпадает с 2008 же! И уродского капса в меню нет!

Comment: 2008 мне вообще-то тоже не очень. Я с 2005 с удовольствием перебрался на 2010, а 2008 почти не пользовался. Но она была очень похожа на 2005. 2010я мне понравилась, а 2012я - совершенно серая, нигде ничего не найдёшь, в общем - полная жесть. Сейчас они частично дизайн привели к нормальному состоянию, но в 2010й всё равно было лучше :)

Answer (score 9):

Он не так уж плох. Хотя проблемы действительно есть.

- *Зачем он сдался фиксированный?* — это выключается в настройках

  - "Preferences" > "Navigation" > галочка "Disable stickyness" — поставить
  - Но стоит обсудить вопрос о том, не стоит ли **включить её всем по умолчанию**.

    - Во-первых, потому что это ломает одну из идей этого редизайна: *сэкономить место по вертикали*. Теперь, как верно намекает вопрос, она занимает место **всё время**, хоть и меньше, так что в результате сделан шаг **от** цели.
    - Во-вторых, потому что при сужении браузера часть элементов верхней панели оказывается **недоступна** (я замерял на 720 пикселях окна, что не так уж и мало; кнопка StackExchange не влезла). Совсем. Тело страницы скроллится по горизонтали, а панель нет. Когда верхняя панель не приклеивается, то прекрасно скроллится вместе с телом страницы. Хотя это можно починить, наверное.
    - В-третьих, потому что это поможет обратной совместимости со старыми пользователями :)
- *Уменьшена кнопка перехода на главную страницу* — от этого же на неё не стало сложнее попадать. Она была *гигантской*. Теперь она всего лишь *крупная*.
- *Всё сделано непонятными иконками* — частично...

  - Почтовый ящик для комментариев прежний. Ок.
  - Выпадашка с другими сообществами, как раньше, со значком SE. Разве что имеет смысл сделать его посинее, чтобы был больше похож на старый, но в целом и так неплохо. У старой версии были (и есть) проблемы с контрастом (низ значка практически сливается с фоном чёрной панели). У новой версии их нет. Совсем.
  - Замена "графика репутации" на "кубок"... двояко. С одной стороны, на это вкладке и правда появляются не только изменения в репутации, но и другие достижения. Скажем, значки. Но с другой стороны, записей об изменении репутации при хоть какой-нибудь активности быстро становится подавляющее большинство. Чёрт, да даже заголовок группы событий за день содержит дельту репутации за весь день! Так что... да, старый значок, наверное, был всё-таки лучше. Но не сильно.
  - Ревью... **всё очень плохо**. Что это? Speech bubble с ручкой? Что он означает? Правка? Комментарий? Я бы это заменил скорее на **очки**, мол, досмотр, детальный осмотр. Подходящее значение могла бы иметь и лупа, но она больше ассоциируется с зумом и скорее собьёт с толку.
- *Переставлены все элементы*

  - *Список сайтов перенесён из первой позиции в последнюю* — косметика. Не вижу проблем с этим. Единственное, что на вид было потеряно, это отношение включения между SO и SE. Из решений сходу приходит в голову только поместить рядом с логотипом сайта dropdown-подобную стрелочку, в которой будут остальные сообщества, а у вкладки сделать заголовок StackExchange. Или как-то иначе. Не знаю, я не особо думал над этим.
  - *Кнопку справки вообще не нашёл* — а она есть. Просто показывается почему-то только незарегистрированным. **Ужасная идея.** В сообществе полно участников с аккаунтами, которым не мешало бы ознакомиться с правилами и туром. Да и помощь в понимании уже прочитанных правил в форме Меты тоже не помешало бы иметь каждому.
  - *Поиск больше не в углу* — да! Он в центре! **И это восхитительно!** Потому что *пользователям* он нужен достаточно часто и это изменение даже помогает, и тем самым изменение может быть полезно и для *участников*, которым придётся меньше махать Священной Кувалдой Дубликата.

Comment: _"от этого же на неё не стало сложнее попадать"_ - вообще-то стало, если ты в неё не пальцем тыкаешь.

Comment: _"Список сайтов перенесён из первой позиции в последнюю — косметика. Не вижу проблем с этим"_ - логотип - переход на главную. На соседний сайт переход должен быть где-то там же, а не на другом конце строки.

Comment: _"Поиск больше не в углу — да! Он в центре! И это восхитительно!"_ - на всех сайтах он в углу. Никто не ищет поиск в центре.

Comment: @Qwertiy (1) разверните мысль; я опробовал мышью и тачскрином и не ощутил значимых изменений. (2) кому это должен? сколько-нибудь устоявшейся практики в этой области я не наблюдаю, разверните мысль. (3) Поиск в центре в поисковых системах, и мы знаем, что многие SO так и воспринимают. В текущем месте его и искать не надо, он как раз сильнее бросается под взгляд.

Comment: мне понравился новый дизайн прежде всего потому что **все элементы панели хорошо видны и различимы**, можно обойтись и без Stylish. Тогда как, например, в дизайне хедера ruSO по умолчанию едва видные серые картинки на чёрном фоне. Пришлось залезть в исходники и [**поменять цвета картинкам в svg-спрайтах**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaMiscellaneous/blob/master/svg/1.2/share-sprite-new.svg). [**Демонстрация**](http://i.imgur.com/sjdvNtl.png), [**тема для ruSO**](https://www.pastery.net/usaprd/). В новом дизайне необходимость в этих манипуляциях отпадает. Спасибо.

Comment: `header.so-header { position: relative !important; }` — вроде работает, header перестаёт быть фиксированным. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных как раз это выключается просто в настройках сайта :)

Comment: @D-side: я бы и не додумался, что что-то можно изменить в хэдере, зайдя в настройки сайта. А Stylish всегда под рукой. Спасибо.

Comment: *"Хотя это можно починить, наверное."* только через одно место. Рисуются две панели, обычная и приклееная - после чего высота приклееной скриптом на onresize выставляется равной высоте обычной.

Comment: @PavelMayorov хоть что-то. Но я всё-таки склоняюсь к варианту "отрубить по умолчанию, позволять включить".

Comment: А мне удобно потому что сразу видишь уведомления. SE ведь программисты для программистов делают и  не могут использовать HTML 5 Notifications API, наверное как с как и https будут год внедрять.

Comment: Я сделал значок [посинее](https://i.imgur.com/aMSUaGI.png)  `.js-site-switcher-button { color: #07C; }`