# Когда уже на ruSO новый дизайн появится?

Tags: обсуждение

Когда уже у нас появится новый дизайн?

[ТУТ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4804/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%91%D1%82) я не вижу ответа на свой вопрос. Почему на SO введен новый, удобный дизайн, а на ruSO еще нет, от чего или от кого это зависит?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Новый дизайн нас тоже ждёт?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4804/%d0%9d%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%91%d1%82)

Comment: Лучше чтоб никогда :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему?

Comment: @Grundy, не нравится он мне))

Comment: Явно не раньше, чем на других сайтах SE.

Comment: @Grundy, http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4804/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%91%D1%82 Прежде чем отмечать дубликатом, найдите мне там ответ на мой вопрос. Меня не интересует, нравится или не нравится новый дизайн. Вопрос в другом.

Comment: @Elena, правильно я вас поддерживаю. Как бы не получилось, что кроме всего прочего, мы останемся без новой версии дизайна сайта

Comment: @Elena Ваш исходный вопрос "Когда уже у нас появится новый дизайн?" по сути содержится в предлагаемом дубликате в виде "Нас это тоже ждёт?". То, что ответа с какими-то конкретными датами ещё нет - не повод задавать аналогичный вопрос снова и снова.

Comment: @alexolut, а что тогда повод? Возможно где-то и есть дата, или есть человек который за это отвечает, потому и спросила! Предыдущий вопрос как раз-таки сформулирован не правильно. Стоило бы задать его так  "нравится вам новый дизайн или нет"

Comment: Дубликаторы, **когда** и **какой будет** - разные вещи.

Comment: Согласен, что это другой вопрос. Ну и ответа от сотрудников SE всё равно в том вопросе нет.

Comment: @stack-it не останемся, просто нужно время.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, тогда ждем =)

Answer (score 3):

Это произошло где-то в районе 1 июня 2017 года: [Новый дизайн навигации по основным разделам сайта!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5312/176217)

Новый дизайн шапки сначала обкатывался на англоязычном сайте, поэтому на локализованных он появился позже. На остальных сайтах сети Stack Exchange шапка пока еще старая.